# set value in text box not more than 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have one text box that allow user to key in value with decimal value.**how to set in text box only can enter only 2 decimal places**. now, user can key in more than 2 decimal places. Below is the code for the text box:

```
<td><b>Payment Amount:</b></td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPayment" runat="server" Enabled="true" CssClass="form-control"/>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPayment" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPayment" ValidationGroup="SubmitGroup" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Please fill in this section" />
                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="rgPayment" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPayment" Display="Dynamic" Type="Double"/>
                            </td>
```

For the text box, on id=rgPayment, i use rangevalidator to validate the value. 
Here the code:

```
protected void lnkbtnB2CProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rgPayment.MaximumValue = "30000";
        rgPayment.MinimumValue = "1";
        txtPayVia.Text = "Retail Banking";
        if (CheckAmount())
        {
            Proceed(Resources.Default.FPXMsgTokenB2C);
            trSupportedChannel.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void lnkbtnB2BProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rgPayment.MaximumValue = "1000000";
        rgPayment.MinimumValue = "2";
        txtPayVia.Text = "Corporate Banking (FPX)";
        if (CheckAmount())
        {
            Proceed(Resources.Default.FPXMsgTokenB2B);
            trSupportedChannel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: Consider adding a question mark, I had to read it a few times before I saw that you were asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [JQuery numeric mask plugin](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/numeric/) and add it's reference on your page. Then use

```
$('[id*="txtPayment"]').numeric({ decimal : ".",  negative : false, scale: 2 });
```